# Initializing variables inside conditional statements

Tags: haskell

Why is it that whenever i initialize variables inside an if statement, for example, I always get a "pare error on input 'let'"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UeUr.png)

Comment: Please type or copy your code into the question, to save others the task of doing so. If you indent by four spaces, or select and press Ctrl-K then it will be nicely formatted.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two corrections that parse for me: attaching an `in` to each `let` or making the two `let` statements be part of a `do` block.

```
case size of
    2 ->
        let from = head temp in
        let to = head (tail temp) in
        ()

case size of
    2 -> do
        let from = head temp
        let to = head (tail temp)
        return ()
```

That said, using `head` and `tail` (and, usually, `length`, presumably used in the definition of `size`) is a code smell. Are you sure you didn't want this instead?

```
case temp of
    [from, to] -> ()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you have two `let` statement. You are only entitled to one `let .. in` or one `.. where` clause. When you use `let` you can have multiple assignments:

```
test :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> IO ()
test x = case x of
    2 -> print "2"
    3 ->
        let 
            y=1
            z=2
        in 
        print $ y+z
```